# how to put a variable in quotes

Tags: php, arrays, variables, quotes

im using the following code to output an array

```
$values = array();
foreach ($album as $a){
$values[] = $a['value'];
}

$string = implode(' or ', $values);

}
```

which returns

```
 1 or 2 or 3
```

now how can I put " " arouns each value, so it will look like

```
 "1" or "2" or "3"
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What did you try? Did it work? If not, why not? I won't downvote (primarily due to the -3 already), but Just Do It ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!empty($values)) {
    $string = '"' . implode('" or "', $values) . '"';
} else {
    $string = 'What do you think you\'re doing!?';
}
```

Comment: This will just quote the whole thing, not the different array parts.

Comment: @Alex, OP wanted string output, not array.

Comment: Not what I meant, but I just noticed the quotes on "or" so I was wrong, this will work.

Answer (score 3):

This is easier in my opinion:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($album as $a){
$values[] = '"'.$a['value'].'"'; //concat quotes on each side of the value
}

$string = implode(' or ', $values);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clean solution that will work properly with an empty array:

```
$string = implode(' or ', array_map(function($value) {
    return '"' . $value . '"';
}, $values));
```

Demo (copied from the `php -a` shell):

```
php > $values = array('foo', 'bar', 'moo');
php >     $string = implode(' or ', array_map(function($value) {
php (         return '"' . $value . '"';
php (     }, $values));
php > echo $string;
"foo" or "bar" or "moo"
php >
```

Comment: probably the most concise solution, but also the hardest to read.

Comment: Well, the example is hard to read. The code itself is pretty readable imo